fastify throw 404 to assets using @fastify/express
I have a cdn bucket ( named and mapped as domain cdn.example.com ). I am using fastify to serve the content. The GCS bucket has multiple folders and lets say the folder I want to serve is  app1 which contains index.html and all other assets. The program( when I run http://localhost:3000) is able to pick index.html but somehow all other assets are not even touched. But when I open http://localhost:3000/index.html , it works end to end.
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true });
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

(async () => {
  await fastify.register(require('@fastify/express'));

  const proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'https://cdn.example.com', // Base URL of your GCS bucket
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/': '/app1/', // Rewrite the path to include the folder name
    },
  });

  fastify.use(proxy);

  fastify.listen({ port: 3000 }, (err, address) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`);
  });
})();

